# White label web applications

Tags: java, spring, grails, branding

I have a web applications (using  JSP, GSP, Grails, Java, Javascript ). 
We want to white label it ( not sure if this is the right word ). What we really want to do is based on the URL from which user is requesting the pages, we want to show different
images, Style sheet, load different message bundle and customize the login page.

What are the different ways to do this ?

We figured out just 1 way to do this :

Intercept the URLs and load different images and style sheet 
Overload getMessage method to get messages from the certain bundle based on the parameter ( such as if external user fetch messages from 'external' folder vs. if internal user fetch from 'internal' folder ) . The challenge here is to overload getmessages method of Spring framework. To me this seems like a crude approach.

I was wondering if there are better approaches out there.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to call it is "theming". Depending on your url you want to set a different theme. [Here's a blog post about using it with Grails](http://fbflex.wordpress.com/2011/08/23/custom-theming-grails-applications/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was thinking though if there are more approaches. How does CMS apps like Drupal do white lablling ?

Comment: I'm not sure how CMS's does it.

Answer (score 0):

Another word is called internationalization. You can use java internationalization framework to make this happen. You will have different property files for different locations. These property files will contain style sheet to be used with different labels in different languages.